# python - setting a user input to an instance

Tags: python, class, input

I want to have a instance, which the user can access using an `input()`statement.
Here are my three instances

```
water1 = waterType("squirtle", 50)
grass1 = grassType("bulbasaur", 50)
fire1 = fireType("charmander", 50)
```

Here's what I mean

```
class waterType(Pokemon):
  """creates a water pokemon"""
  pokemon_type = "water"
  damage = 10
  def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp
  def growl(self):
    print("Splish Splosh")
  def attack(self):
    enemy = input("Who do you want to attack?")  <--- over here, I would enter "fire1"
    """attribute error occurs here"""
    if (enemy.pokemon_type == "fire"):
      global damage
      water1.damage = water1.damage*2
      enemy.hp = enemy.hp - water1.damage
      return enemy.hp
      print ("It was super effective!")
      print (enemy.hp)
```

If I take all the "enemy" and replace it with "fire1", everything works perfectly.  However, then I would need to manually input every single fire-type instance.

If it is not possible to assign an instance to an input, is there any way to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening right now is that you are assigning `enemy` to the string "fire1", rather than the variable.

This could be achieved as such:

`enemy = eval(input("Who do you want to attack?"))`

This should then reference the actual object called 'fire1'. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted!